# Better to keep vec4 instead of vec3 to avoid always casting?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, vector, glm-math

I'm using OpenGL, and in my code I have some unreadable and annoying lines like:

```
newChild->dposition = dvec_4(dvec_4(newChild->boundingVerts[2].position, 1) + newChild->parent->dposition);
```

The idea was to keep positions in vec3s, with many objects in the scene it could amount to a good saving in storage, and even more importantly reduce the size of buffers sent to the graphics card. But it leads to really hard to read code casting back and fourth, plus all the casts I imagine do cost something. So is it better to keep vec4s to avoid the casting?

Comment: Which linear algebra library is `dvec_4` from?  Doesn't look like [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net).

Comment: @GLM. - genpfault from the library that goes typedef glm::vec4 dvec_4. Haha, I'm not sure if it's of any benefit.

Comment: Why would you need `vec4`s in that particular code at all? Why would you ever need a vec4 on the cpu side? That would only be necessary for playing some tricks with perspective, but one seldom really needs this.

Comment: @derhass Umm, I'm making a planet, and I've quickly run into floating point issues. It's 600km, floating point 600,000, and at the surface there's lots of jiggling. There's a lot I'll have to do with origin rebasing, it's pretty hard, for me at least.

Comment: @derhass: re: `vec4`s CPU-side, 16-byte alignment for SIMD operations?

Comment: I'd just mention all these tricks wouldn't have to be pulled off if graphics cards handled double precision well, could make something about the size of the solar system with excellent precision.

Comment: Well, my comment was about vec3 vs vec4, not double vs. float. That's a totally different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to all of the code, it is hard to say.
However, I would rather say that using vec4s might bring performance/code quality benefits:

- Guessing that the data is likely used on the GPU, it is likely more efficient to load/store a vec4, than a vec3. I am not exactly sure, but I do not think that there is a single instruction to load a vec3. It will be broken into loading a vec2 and a float I think.
- Later, you could easily store some additional data into that additional float.
- Less casting and making code more readable.
- Depending on the memory layout/member types of your struct, it might be so that the struct is aligned to 16 bytes anyway undoing your "memory optimization".

If something is wrong, please correct me.